Why can't I access my local network through my WireGuard VPN?
I'm trying to use a WireGuard VPN I have set up to reach machines on my home network. When I run ip route list, it looks like everything is set up correctly:
> ip route list
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.204 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.204 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.1 dev wgvpn proto static metric 1 
192.168.1.1 dev wgvpn proto static scope link metric 1

and I am able to reach 192.168.1.1 over the VPN:
> ip route get 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1 dev wgvpn src 192.168.9.142 uid 1000 
    cache 

However, whenever I try to connect to any other 192.168.0.* address, it goes outside the VPN:
> ip route get 192.168.0.127
192.168.0.127 dev wlan0 src 192.168.0.204 uid 1000 
    cache 

What am I missing here?

Okay, I was able to solve this by adding a WireGuard route for 192.168.0.0/24, but I've still got some questions: (1) Why did this work (route specificity)? and (2) What would I have to do if I connected to a wireless network that declared a route for, say, 192.168.1.0/24? Would I just have to keep declaring additional rules to override the specificity of each subnet?

It is indeed impossible to unambiguously address two connected networks that seem to have the same addresses. You have to avoid it; for that, you plan your network ahead of time for your sub-networks to not overlap. Or renumber (change numbers) them, if they do overlap. Or you can go nuts and implement all the sorts of address translation; good luck with that, see you in the madhouse.

If you never need to access any "local" LAN hosts (except sending the WG-encapsulated frames to the LAN gateway), and assuming you are talking about wg-quick, you can probably switch away from the "trick" that comes with the implicit Table=auto for AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0 (by setting Table= to a number, even 51820 is good IIRC), to some routing policy that is more "aggresive" (like, have something like not iif lo ipproto udp sport 51820 lookup 51820 instead of the "trick").

(The aforementioned "trick" is a set of ip rules that make sure traffics with destination covered by a non-default route in the main table will not be routed into the tunnel, with some iptables / nftables rules and a sysctl setting that make sure things would work with reverse path filtering.)
